# Kubernetes: use volumeClaimTemplate to select admin-provisioned PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I have created some Persistent Volumes myself. Is it possible to make the `volumeClaimTemplates` in my Stateful Set select those? It seems that it will always provision new persistent volumes, rather than use the existing ones.

*Kubernetes: 1.5*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `selector` option. If you label your pv's accordingly, the pods would use the volumes you previously created.

Example From: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
  storageClassName: slow
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      release: "stable"
    matchExpressions:
      - {key: environment, operator: In, values: [dev]}
```

Even though it is a PersistentVolumeClaim, it should be applicable to your volumeClaimTemplate